# Is there way to automatically clean up empty groups in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am importing SVG-vector image to Illustrator and manually fix them. There are many bounding box (like art box) which will removed and after that there is many empty group exists. How to clean them? Is there way to automatically clean up empty groups in Illustrator?

[image: There is many empty groups which cannot select]

Comment: Select all the goups that are empty (without an arrow), by clicking on the targets, then do Object > Ungroupl.

Comment: How do you get this to happen. When i import a svg Illustrator kills of all empty groups. Try running path > clean up. Esimerkkui olis kiva

Comment: I remove some artbox after inserting SVG. It creates empty groups which need to automatically removed

Comment: That works!  "Try running path > clean up" Thanks / Kiitos! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok after spending a few minutes on making illustrator generate extra groups on purpose, so that I can test. Atleast on my document the redundant groups get killed by choosing **Object → Path → Clean Up...**

Answer (score 0):

In Illustrator, if you delete all of the elements of a group, the group itself is deleted. (you can see this in the Layers Panel.)

If you are referring to **shapes with no fill or stroke,** then you can find them by drawing a new rectangle with no shape or fill and using <kbd>select</kbd> / <kbd>same</kbd> / <kbd>fill and stroke</kbd> to select all shapes that match these criteria. Now you can delete them.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it wont solve my problem. Please check attached picture which shows many empty groups which cannot select.

Comment: Did you try selecting the empty group directly in the Layers panel by clicking the small white circle on the right? Can you delete it then?

Comment: I can but I want to know some automatical way to remove all empty groups

Comment: I guess you will have to use Illustrator scripting then to do this automatically. I'm afraid I can't help with that, though.

Comment: Illustrator scripting is fine, but I cannot programming it